# How to read a .docx file with "js docx" library generated with it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, docx

I want to read a file with the "docx" library.

I have already generated the docx document, but what I want to do is fetch the document again to validate it since I have added a "fingerprint" to it to validate if they have edited the originally generated document, kind of like what banks do.

I have seen examples like the following.

```
const buffer = fs.readFileSync('./uploads/ta.docx');
const doc = new Document(buffer);
```

But this is throwing me the following error:
`TypeError: e.sections is not iterable`

I have also tried the following code:

```
const buffer = fs.readFileSync('./uploads/ta.docx');
const doc = new Document();
doc.load(buffer);
```

And it gives me the same error again: `TypeError: e.sections is not iterable`

Is there another way to do the document validation or am I going astray?
I appreciate your time and thanks in advance.

Comment: The example that I have seen requires a config for the Document constructor. Can you provide the link for your source?

Comment: I looked at the docs and its says the library is for generating docx files. There is a menu point for exporting but not importing.